# How to use boost::property_tree to parse JSON with array root

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

How can I get data from JSON with array as root node by using Boost.PropertyTree?

```
[
  {
      "ID": "cc7c3e83-9b94-4fb2-aaa3-9da458c976f7",
      "Type": "VM"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The array elements are just values with a key named "" for property tree:

```
for (auto& array_element : pt) {
    for (auto& property : array_element.second) {
        std::cout << property.first << " = " << property.second.get_value<std::string>() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
ID = cc7c3e83-9b94-4fb2-aaa3-9da458c976f7
Type = VM
```

---

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d565d18da91a94e0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss(R"([
    {
        "ID": "cc7c3e83-9b94-4fb2-aaa3-9da458c976f7",
        "Type": "VM"
    }
    ]
    )");

    ptree pt;
    json_parser::read_json(iss, pt);

    for (auto& array_element : pt) {
        for (auto& property : array_element.second) {
            std::cout << property.first << " = " << property.second.get_value<std::string>() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see I can't use something like in documentation `pt.get<std::string>("key");`, because root array doesn't have key and I have to use iteration over array, am I right?

Comment: That's possible. This is just the first thing I tried. It seems likely that this restriction exists: how would you handle repeated keys anyways - let alone repeated "" keys :)

Comment: @sehe is it possible to find out the child in a JSON using boost ptree ?

Comment: @Milind ? perhaps you can ask a (clearer) question on the main site.